# Restlet: Only 1 request per second

Tags: java, testing, restlet

I'm doing load testing of my web service with Servlet, but I can do only 1 request per second. Why and how can I do more requests?

Here is my testing method:

```
public void testByMovieLens(String pathToData, int maxData) throws Exception {
    if(api_key == null){
        throw new Exception("No api key.");
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathToData));

    String line;
    String[] parts;

    int counter = 0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        parts = line.split("\t");

        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8111/preferences?api_key="+api_key+"&user_id="+parts[0]+"&item_id="+parts[1]+"&score="+parts[2]);

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        BufferedReader brr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String linee;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while((linee = brr.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(linee);
        }
        brr.close();

        if(++counter % 100 == 0){
            System.out.println("done "+counter);
        }
        if(counter == maxData){
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("All done for "+((System.currentTimeMillis() - timer) * .001)+" seconds");

    br.close();
}
```

P.S. At the testing time my web service is doing nothing. I'm provided empty mocks, but Restlet still handles only 1 request per second

Comment: Consider concurrency libraries. Not much of an answer, so it's a comment. Like @DNA mentioned, we don't really know what you're doing, so we don't really know how to help you make it faster.

Comment: Suggest you first add some more detailed timing logging, and/or run a profiler over the code, to see where the actual delay is occurring.

Comment: I suggest you use JMeter or similar to simulate load with real concurrent calls.